# Webrtc: cannot stop remoteStream audio

Tags: webrtc

I am playing a remote webrtc stream.
When I run that:

```
remoteStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
remoteStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
```

Video stops but audio continues: any idea ?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jP]ID.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine in Firefox, may be a bug in chrome. 
After calling `remoteStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();`
Track `readyState` is changing from `live` to `ended`.

You can report @ https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/list

For time being you can set audio/video tag volume as follows

```
document.getElementById("remotevideo").volume = 0;
```